# Python Toggle between two class implementations clean code

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, toggle

I would like toggle between two implementations of the same class depending on an environment variable in the os.
one of the cases I would like to use it, it to toggle between logging to a remote server and logging into a local disk.

what I have so far is the following implementation:

```
import abc
class AbstractLogger(object):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def log(message):
        pass




class LocalLogger(AbstractLogger):

    def __init__(self):
     # open file here

    def log(self, message):
        print('write to file')




class RemoteLogger(AbstractLogger):

     def __init__(self):
        # open socket here

    def log(self, message):
        print('write to socket')



import os
class mode(object):
is_local=os.getenv('key')
    mylogger=None

@staticmethod
def get_logger():
  if mode.is_local and mode.logger is None:
      mode.mylogger=LocalLogger()
  else:
      mode.logger=RemoteLogger()
  return mode.mylogger
```

then the usage of my code will be like this:

```
from mode import mode
mode.get_logger().log('write this')
```

or

```
from mode import mode
logging=mode.get_logger()
logging.log('write this')
```

That code is not clean especially when we consider I would write this every couple of rows at every class in my project, my best wish is to use it like this:

```
import mode
mode.log('joy')
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after research on how python logging works I come out with a solution.

all class stays the same but `class mode` which removed, and **mode.py** file is:

```
import os

mylogger=LocalLogger() if os.getenv('key')=='value' else RemoteLogger()

@staticmethod
def log(message):
    mylogger.log(message)
```

then I can do:

```
import mode
mode.log('joy')
```

any thoughts?